# What does the Team Recharge Delay on soldier class mods do?

Tags: borderlands

I have found this soldier Leader Class Mod:

[image: Leader Class Mod]

What does the -20% Team Recharge Delay stand for? Is it a good thing or a drawback of the mod? I guess it should be something like the Deploy Skill (that reduces the cooldown time of the scorpio turret) for all the team, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It [means](http://borderlands.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Whats_team_recharge_delay) that the shield recharge cool-off time is reduced by 20%, for the entire team. In other words, your shields will start recharging earlier after taking damage.